# How to find folders that do not begin with tilde ("~")

Tags: linux, find

I am trying to find folders, excluding those that begin with the tilde ("~").  I have tried the following but results are zero. It looks like `find` is interpreting the tilde as a wildcard.

```
find . -type d -not -path '*/\~*'
find . -type d -not -path '*/~*'
find . -type d -not -regex '.*/~.*'
find . -type d -not -regex '.*/\~.*'
```

My version of find is `find (GNU findutils) 4.6.0`.

Comment: What do you mean by _results are zero_? Do you mean you don't even see `.`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To skip the `./path/to/~dir` folders, but not the `./path/to/~dir/subdir`, as others have already said, you can do:

```
find . ! -name '~*' -type d -print
```

If you also want not to *descend* into those folders (and find further folders there), you'd do:

```
find . -name '~*' -prune -o -type d -print
```

That tells `find` to prune the branches rooted at the directories whose name starts with `~`.

That should be mostly¹ functionally equivalent to your:

```
find . -type d ! -path '*/~*'
```

Except that the latter doesn't do pruning, so still looks inside those directories even though it prints none of them so is less efficient.

---

<sup>¹ there is some difference in that the first `*` in `*/~*` may fail to match on file names that contain invalid characters</sup>

Comment: Thank you. The `find . -name '~*' -prune -o -type d -print` works as desired.

I am curious as to why the `-regex` or the `-path` did not work.

Comment: @user1822391, in which way does it not work? Does it fail to skip some directories (do you have an example of such a directory), or does it skip too many directories (again, do you have an example of a directory which it shouldn't have skipped?)

Comment: Hmmm... very strange.  Now it is working.  I think I may have gotten the incorrect syntax for regex originally.  What I am trying to do is list all directories that do not have a component that begins with certain special char.  So the `-prune` option works. And I was able to confirm that command works now: `find <PATH> -type d -not -regex '.*/\(\.\|\!\|_\|\~\).*'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `-name` option to specify what your expression is testing against.  The following works for me:

```
find . -type d ! -name '~*'
```

Answer (score 0):

The name test should do fine:

```
find . -type d ! -name '~*'
```